# Calling Javascript function from server side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

On a button click i am calling a server side function in which i am calling a Javascript function like

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(), 
    "scriptsKey", 
    "<script type=\"text/JavaScript\" language=\"javascript\">test();</script>");
```

But Javascript function is not calling.

Comment: Do you actually have a method called `Test()` on the page you are injecting your script?

Comment: You cannot just call JavaScript from server side. Do you understand the problem at all?

Comment: Yes i have a method test() in my page

Comment: @slugster can't i call a javascript function from server side

Comment: Can you see this script block being rendered in the source of the page?

Comment: @user2798259 you don't call javascript from the server, you *inject* script from the server into the client-side page. Have you checked to make sure the script is in the page? Also have you checked developer tools in the browser? Could be an issue in your JS.

Comment: Do you have ScriptManager on your page?

Comment: @Egor4eg yes i have ScriptManager in my page

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can call the function from code behind like this :

MyForm.aspx.cs

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "AnotherFunction();", true);
}
```

MyForm.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>My Page</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Test() {
        alert("hi");
        $("#ButtonRow").show();
    }
    function AnotherFunction()
    {
        alert("This is another function");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form2" runat="server">
<table>
    <tr><td>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="SearchCategory" runat="server" onchange="Test()"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  BorderStyle="Solid">
               <asp:ListItem>Merchant</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem>Store</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem>Terminal</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="ButtonRow"style="display:none">
         <td>
            <asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="Click Here" OnClick="MyButton_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table> 
</form>
```

Comment: Not working after adding the above code

Comment: I checked it twice. It's working for me well. There might be other issues in your code i guess. It would be better if you could show your code.

Comment: following is the funtion i am calling on button click.i am not able to post code here its too long.

Comment: Is there any ajax request in your page?

Comment: No there is not Ajax Request

Comment: Then i guess you should provide the code. Otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: Hi I have made some changes in your form exactly what i wants to do.Now Javascript function is not calling.Code at http://jsfiddle.net/e4kGs/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e4kGs/1/

Try updating your code like this. You can use onchange="FunctionName()" attribute in the RadioButtonList control and must provide that function before calling it.

Comment: Hi, I had written the function to make visible the row on radiobuttonlist onchange function.It is working.But after the button becomes visible when you click the button javascript function is not calling from server side.I think i am clear if not u can ask about the problem.

Comment: I have updated the answer. It's may be what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks Finally working

Comment: when I used that it works but after postback, it works automaticly? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "scr", "javascript:test();", true);
```

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks.`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "setValueinEditor();", true);`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Hope it will work for you too.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "isActive", "Test();", true);
```

I have edited the html page which you have provided. The updated page is as below

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title>My Page</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Test() {
                alert("Hello Test!!!!");
                $('#ButtonRow').css("display", "block");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="SearchCategory" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                        BorderStyle="Solid">
                        <asp:ListItem>Merchant</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Store</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Terminal</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="ButtonRow" style="display: none">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="Click Here" OnClick="MyButton_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#<%=SearchCategory.ClientID%> input").change(function () {
            alert("hi");
            $("#ButtonRow").show();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Form at http://jsfiddle.net/e4kGs/ and on button click it is calling following function in server side.                                      protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "Test();", true);
        }

Comment: Well I moved the "Test" function to the "head" tag and my code worked. Also in my code I am calling "test" function with small "t". Thats a typo there. I have changed it now. :)

Comment: Can u post code which worked for u

Comment: Hi,If i add modify Test() in head as function Test() {
         alert("Hello Test!!!!");
         $("#ButtonRow").show();
     }

Comment: ButtonRow is not getting visible