# How to call JavaScript from C# - Cordova/PhoneGap

Tags: c#, javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm using cordova/phonegap to make a windows phone app, i'm trying to call a script from C# when an event fires.

Is there anyway to do this?

here's my class so far.

```
public void register(string options)
{
        // This is executed asynchronously
        if (!TryFindChannel())
            DoConnect();
}


void httpChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
{
        // Finished asynchronous task in "register" method
        Trace("Channel opened. Got Uri:\n" + httpChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
        SaveChannelInfo();

        Trace("Subscribing to channel events");
        SubscribeToService();
        SubscribeToNotifications();

        // SEND CHANNEL URI TO JAVASCRIPT

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176086/calling-javascript-function-from-server-side

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that I'm using cordova/phonegap to make a windows phone app not asp.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution, admittedly not the best one but works for me.

I created a singleton class called WebViewHandler which looks like this

```
class WebViewHandler
{
    private static WebViewHandler instance;
    public bool isWebViewReady { get { return webView != null; } }
    public WPCordovaClassLib.CordovaView webView;

    private WebViewHandler()
    {

    }

    public void setWebView(ref WPCordovaClassLib.CordovaView webView)
    {
        this.webView = webView;
    }

    public static WebViewHandler getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new WebViewHandler();
        }
        return instance;
    } 
}
```

Then I set the webview in the constructor on the HomePage like so:

```
 public HomePage()
 {
      InitializeComponent();
      CordovaView.Loaded += CordovaView_Loaded;
      WebViewHandler.getInstance().setWebView(ref CordovaView); 
 }
```

Once the WebView is set I can then call InvokeScript from any other class:

```
WebViewHandler.getInstance().webView.CordovaBrowser.InvokeScript("MyJavaScriptFunctionThatIWishToCall");
```

Comment: nice one:) glad you found a solution and posted it

Comment: no problem, hopefully it will save others hours of searching like I did.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("myFunction", "one", "two", "three");
```

`InvokeScript` executes a scripting function defined in the currently loaded document, and passes the function an array of string parameters.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402838%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Obviously you have to have the `JavaScript` function defined in the loaded document.

Depending on your view it may work like this:

```
this.CordovaView.Browser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "yourJavascriptFunction(); " });
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this from my custom plugin class which inherits from BaseCommand which has no reference to the webview as far as I can tell.

Comment: hi @benka i am calling my js function from c# with same way as you have written, but i am unable to call and i am getting exception number x800088 like wise which is not provide the specific reason, can you please tell me why it is that i am unable to call my funciton, i am calling like following.

myBrowser.InvokeScript("myFun", "val1", "val2"); OR

string[] params={"val1","val2"};
myBrowser.InvokeScript("myFun", params);

above both are not working. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use DispatchCommandResult(); as outlined in the cordova documents. That way you can call the c# method, send whatever you need in the callback, and then just execute the javascript from within javascript.

Comment: I'm waiting on an event to call the javascript, so you can't call tbe c# method

Answer (score 0):

Try this example :

```
string str="<script>alert(\"ok\");</script>";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", str, false);
```