# Error UnathorizedException when invoking JavaScript from C#

Tags: c#, javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8, invokescript

I am trying to call JavaScript code from C# in a PhoneGap (Cordova) Windows Phone 8 application. Following the steps of this accepted answer thread: [How to call JavaScript from C# - Cordova/PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864477/how-to-call-javascript-from-c-sharp-cordova-phonegap)

I am supposed to be able to access a method in the Javascript part or execute a  hardcoded JS code. But, I am encountering this error:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
>   An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
>   ERROR: Exception in ProcessCommand :: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   ERROR: failed to InvokeMethodNamed :: pluginMethod on Object :: Example

My code is (is a native Plugin):

```
namespace WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands
{
    public class Example : Cordova.Commands.BaseCommand
    {
        public void pluginMethod(string options)
        {
          //The error is caused in this line
          PGWebBrowserHandler.getInstance().webView.CordovaBrowser
              .InvokeScript("eval", 
                            new string[] { "alert('Is it running?!');" });
        }
    }
}
```

`PGWebBrowserHandler` is the name of the singleton class given in the previous mentioned thread in order to have access to the `CordovaBrowser` from any C# class.

The error (`FileNotFoundException,` `UnauthorizedAccessException` and `TargetInvocationException`) is not caused by the `InvokeScript()` method, is caused previously by obtaining the `webView,` which doesn't crash but debugging it, a lot of is methods are causing `UnauthorizedAccessException.`

I hope my explanations are clear. I've been searching it in Google but I've not found a solution or workaround anywhere.
Anybody know the reason of these problems? Invoking the `invokeScript()` method from the `MainPage.cs` also cause exceptions.

Comment: The System.IO.FileNotFoundException does not always occur. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            () =>
            {
                PGWebBrowserHandler.getInstance().webView.CordovaBrowser
                    .InvokeScript("eval",
                      new string[] { "alert('Is it running?!');" });
            });
```

Comment: I also tried this code before opening this thread but Visual Studio gives me this error:
'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Action)'and doesn't let me compile.
Thanks anyways for the answer.