# How to restart Cordova WP8 app?

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have a WP8 Cordova app that has one page locally and then it redirects to a server for further functionality. Both pages have the cordova JS API's available and things work well.

Except that when I want to go to the local start page again. Any anchors to it (pointing to `x-wmapp0:www/index.html`) do not work on the HTML side.

In addition, any tricks with plugins and invocations of `CordovaBrowser.Navigate()` result in `UnauthorizedAccessException` errors.

The fallback has been for me to try to go back in browser history like this:

```
window.history.go(-window.history.length + 1);
```

But this doesn't do anything if I spend any time in the remote pages at all. So this isn't applicable either!

Is there a decent way to get to the starting page? With help from C# or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

So the `UnauthorizedAccessException` stuff came from thread issues. (The VS Express for WP can sometimes hide the details of an exception pretty well.)

This is a complete plugin that performs the redirection with neatest elegance available.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands;

namespace Cordova.Extension.Commands
{
    public class Jumper : BaseCommand
    {
        /** Instruct the browser component to go to beginning. */
        public void goHome(string unused)
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                var webview = WebViewHandler.getInstance().webView;
                webview.CordovaBrowser.Navigate(webview.StartPageUri);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The `WebViewHandler` is a singleton for sharing the Cordova WebView to plugins, described in [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19973078/308668) (thanks @MikeBryant!).

Comment: Funnily enough this approach shares similar freeze characteristics like the `history.go()` method. What on earth does IEMobile do there between pages...