# Call javascript function from server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When I use this code works fine:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"hwa","alert('Hello World');",true);
```

but when I try to call MyFunction using this code doesn't work:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "MyFunction()", true);
```

page.aspx head section:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

      function MyFunction() {
         alert('Hello World');
      }
  </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Read the generated source.

Comment: You sure `MyFunction()` call is below its definition in the client code (in the browser) like @SLaks suggests?

Comment: in browser, page source shows me MyFunction is generated correctly in page's head section.

Comment: Does adding semicolon e.g. "MyFunction();" help?

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter, Thank you so much, adding semicolon solved the problem.

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "MyFunction();", true);

Comment: @farhang67 glad it was helpful, good luck in further development

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are trying your second snippet without commenting out or erasing the first? I mean, maybe you have this in your server side code:

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"hwa","alert('Hello World');",true);

//... some lines

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "MyFunction()", true);

Because if you use only one or the other, both snippets work.

Comment: No I commented the first snippet when runnig the second one

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "Myfunction();", true);
```

Source: [Calling Javascript function from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176086/calling-javascript-function-from-server-side)