# RegisterStartUpScript does not fire javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am calling a JS function from Codebehind, the function is supposed to `toggle()` or `show()` a `tr` in the `dom`. I am using the following for this purpose:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), DateTime.Now.ToString(), "ToggleTr(1)", true);
```

If I am in a debugging mode, this works fine magically, but seems to work very spontaneously otherwise. Hence, I used a `timeout 500` for this, but I believe that is not a good approach in itself. So my other try was:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), DateTime.Now.ToString(), "window.onload = function() {ToggleTr(1);}", true);
```

But this does not help either. NOTE: I am using webform `aspx` pages templated under a `MasterPage`, So I cannot use the `head` or a `form` tag either. This is what I have in my `aspx` page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlEmployeeDetails" runat="server">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ToggleTr(showFlag) {
                if (showFlag == 1) {
                    $("#trSupervisor").show();
                }
                else if (showFlag == 0) {
                    $("#trSupervisor").hide();
                }
            }
</script>
```

Secondly, I am not calling this on `PageLoad`, the calls vary on several event handlers executed.. What should I do here??

Comment: If you want to Call a javaScript Function from code behind, you can try this way. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176086/calling-javascript-function-from-server-side/19176323#19176323

Comment: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` is to be used when you're working with `UpdatePanels`, and then you should pass the `UpdatePanel` and its `type` on the parameters. If you're not using one, you can just use `Page.RegisterStartupScript` and keep the parameters as they are.

Comment: @MelanciaUK It says the method is deprecated and obsolete.

Comment: My bad. Wrong one. It should be `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.90).aspx